# How to let google index my database driven pages - that are not direcly linked to

Tags: database, seo, indexing

Hi in simple terms have a company listing website.

I have a database of companies people can search and results are shown - fine.

Now what I want to do is open my database or these database driven pages to google so they can be indexed - so in an ideal world if someone searches for 'xyz company' their profile on my company listing website could be dispalyed in the search results.

As these pages wont all have direct links to them how can I get google to spider them?

Thanks!

EDIT***
OK to clarify they will be accessible by links ie "site.com/company?id=1" maybe even seo friendly urls if I can sort out dupe company name issues.  It was more that the actual links wont all be listed on the site but now as others have suggested  I can return all of these to a sitemap.xml but as per BiAiB's comment Google sounds like it will cap the number they will index...

I like the idea of a company by county page though that would work with direct links.

Comment: I think you have both the problem and the solution here: "As these pages wont all have direct links to them how can I get google to spider them?" Just make search available via GET requests and have a listing of them somewhere accessible for spiders

Comment: If I have say 20,000 companies is this still good to have google spider them all?

Comment: google will grant you a limit of pages crawled depending on your score. So what can happen is that the spider stops while crawling 20000pages and then miss pages you really want to be indexed. I'm really not an expert on the subject you should check out SEO related forums, they often deal with this kind of concerns.

Comment: Why won't all the pages have links to them? Can you not add pages that do have links to them, based on criteria (e.g. alphabetised lists, location, etc).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should make an [XML sitemap](http://www.sitemaps.org/), then submit it to Google Webmaster Tools.

Google have a page about it here: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156184

Another way would be to make an HTML sitemap that contains all the pages, and have a link to it in the footer. Without any links to the content, Google will likely not think it's very important, and won't give it high rankings.

Comment: I am using a cms that has a automatic site map builder - but as yet it does not list these db driven pages.  But the number of these pages might be up to thousands is this number still good for an xml site map?

Comment: Just checked and google apparantly allow up to 50,000 links per site map - http://www.seroundtable.com/archives/021559.html - so this would actually work with a lot of links....

Answer (score 1):

Your ideal solution is to create a contextual link structure to all your businesses.

This not only lets Google find your businesses but also helps Google categorise them.

It would probably also help your visitors.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by 'contextual'?
I assume something like "site.com/county/industry_sector/company_name" as opposed to /page.php?company_id=1

Comment: Yep. The structure of the URL is not so important but would be nice. I'm talking more about how you provide links on the website. e.g. a list of country links that each go to a list of industry sectors in that country, which each contain the businesses. This would be great for users and also help the spiders index your businesses.